# Event isn't firing properly until second button press

Tags: reactjs, events, react-hooks

Checked all the related questions, couldn't find one similar to my issue unfortunately.

I have an array of user objects that I map out into a table. Next to each user's ID is a delete button, when it's pressed, I fire an event to remove the user from the array.

I've tried adding a second onClick function to the button, first declaring what the user object is, then firing the removal, I've also tried e.stopPropagation() thinking maybe it wasn't bubbling correctly.

```
const UsersTable = ({ users, setUsers, callback }) => {
    const [selectedUser, setSelectedUser] = useState(null);
    const removeUser = user => {
        setSelectedUser(user)
        callback(user)
    };

    return (
        {
            users.map(user => 
                <div className="userRow">
                    <div className="deleteButton" onClick={()=> removeUser(user)}>
                        {user.name}
                    </div>
                </div>
            )
        }
    )
};
```

If I run the callback with a defined user, it works properly. When using this however, the first time I click the button, it gives me an error saying the user can't be null, and on the second press, it fires properly. Is there something I'm doing wrong? Why won't it work properly the first press.

Comment: Show us a producible example

Comment: How are the users being set up?  What is the callback code?  There's not enough to go on here.

Answer (score 0):

I think this may be a synchronicity issue. Instead of running `callback` inside of `removeUser`, try putting it in `useEffect`. https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-effect.html